# Autogenerate columns in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, scripting, data-manipulation, vba

Data manipulation challenge of the week:

I have an Excel-sheet looking like this:

```
ProductGroup    ProductName
------------    -----------
Mountain Bikes  MTB Thunder
Mountain Bikes  MTB Lightning
Road Bikes      Road Killer
Road Bikes      Road First Class
```

I need to add two extra columns with autogenerated text around the Product Names like this:

```
Text1                               Text2 
------------                        -----------
I love MTB Thunder so much          MTB Thunder and MTB Thunder
I love MTB Lightning so much        MTB Lightning and MTB Lightning
I love Road Killer so much          Road Killer and Road Killer
I love Road First Class so much     Road First Class and Road First Class
```

The text only for illustration...

I can think of a few way to accomplish this. Making a script to load and manipulate the Excel-file, use SQL Server Integration Services, but I can't help thinking that there's an easier way to do this!?

What is the simplest and most elegant way to make this data-manipulation?

Even though I've been programming for more than a decade I've never touched the Macros in Excel... but maybe they are a solution?

Any suggestions?

Regards
Alex

Comment: "Road Killer"? I don't like the sound of that. Are all bikes this aggressive these days?!!

Comment: Yup, not suitable for kids these iron studs. I'm into MTB myself, not the road killing stuff though... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for macros here - simple formulas should suffice.

Assuming your Productname is in column B, starting in row 2, these formula will give you your texts:

Text1: `="I love "&B2&" so much"`

Text2: `=B2&" and "&B2`

Then just copy the formulas to to fill the columns.

Comment: Of cause! (And a bit embarrassing I didn't think of it). No need to make it more complex than that... Thanks for your prompt reply. ;)